# changed site from http to https and now its unreachable by google

Tags: google-search-console, https, web-crawlers, http

I move my website from http to https and now it does not appear in the google search resutls, it was appearing on the top search resutls.
In google search consolte when I do fetch for the website it says its unreachable. 
If I use the robots.txt tester I get this error:
You have a robots.txt file that we are currently unable to fetch. In such cases we stop crawling your site until we get hold of a robots.txt, or fall back to the last known good robots.txt file

I cannot see a robots.txt file in my public_html file

Comment: I can access your robots.txt file. Add your new site(with this name `https://yoursitename.com` ) first in Google search console and try again to fetch. I don't see any problem right now. If you still face it, then give us proper screenshot.

Comment: To note for anyone answering this question is that google searches for `opeturmo.com` and `site:opeturmo.com` don't seem to show the home page.

Comment: Your site has many 404 errors for the pages that remain in Google Search. It is possible that Google de-listed the main page not because there is an issue with your main page, but because there are issues with all the rest of your pages.